# Do I need a transaction here?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web application in which users create objects that get stored in a MySQL database.  Each object has a globally unique identifier that is stored in a table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `uidlist`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `uidlist` (
`uid` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`chcs` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii;
```

When a new object is to be created and stored I generate a new uid and ensure that it does not already exist in the `uidlist` table. (I should mention that collisions are rare since the potential range of UIDs I have is very large).

No issues here - it works just fine.  However, with an increasing number of users wanting to simultaneously create + store objects the need to check uidlist is liable to become a bottleneck.

To circumvent the problem here is what I have done:

I have a secondary table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `uidbank`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `uidbank` (
`uid` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`used` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii;
```

I pre-populate this table at short intervals via a CRON job - which ensures that it always has 1000 uid values that are tested for uniqueness.

When a live user requires a new UID I do the following:

```
function makeUID()
{
 global $dbh;
 $sql = "DELETE FROM `uidbank` WHERE used = '1';";
 //discard all "used" uids from previous hits on the bank 
 $sql .= "UPDATE `uidbank` SET used = '1' WHERE used = '0' LIMIT 1;";
 //setup a new hit
 $dbh->exec($sql);
 //be done with that

 $sql = "SELECT uid FROM `uidbank` WHERE used = '1'";
 $uid = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchColumn();
 //now pickup the uid hit we just setup
 return $uid;
 //return the "safe" uid ready for use
}
```

No issues here either.  It works perfectly well in my single user test environment.  However, my SQL skills are pretty basic so I am not 100% sure that

- this is the right way to handle the job
- that my "safe" UID pickup method will not return unsafe values because in the mean time another user has been assigned the same UID.

I'd much appreciate any tips on how this scheme might be improved.

Comment: wherever you feel that you need to work with multiple tables and any change in any table will affect others then you should use transaction

Comment: You can't use PHP to enforce data integrity, and you're doing that. The other thing you're doing is creating a procedure that "generates" unique identifiers. We have them already. It's MySQL's `auto_increment` and `UUID()` functions and they work properly. Is there a reason you are rolling your own solution? It creates more problems than it fixes.

Comment: Read my comments in response to @Olly W.  I am using my own routine to generate unique ids because they are for use in the outside world where they need to have a specific structure.  Having said that, +1 for your remark that one should not use PHP to enforce data integrity.

Comment: @DroidOS - I understand that people use certain keys for "outside" purpose. However, even though I can disagree with you that there's no reason you can't use autoincrements - is there a reason you can't use proper unique universally identifier generated by MySQL (`UUID()` function), that also conforms to UUID specification and really **is** globally unique? If you want to roll your own solution, the only way you can do it is by having unique constraint and handling failure scenarios when there are clashes.

Comment: @N.B. - One issue with UUIDs is their size: way too big.  Global/universal are relative terms.  In the first place I cannot dictate the format used by the UIDs - that comes from elsewhere and I have to comply with it. That apart in the present context global/universal is for a relatively small universe so a 9 char alphanumeric string is sufficient.  I have now rolled in my own constraint solution to ensure data integrity and it appears to hold - see my comment to Olly W below.

Comment: From integrity POV - unique constraint handles the "uniqueness", you won't get clashes that will find their way into the db. As for second part of the question, yes - you do need transactions - there's a delete and update present, you don't want one failing, other one succeeding or vice-versa. For performance purposes, I suggest you put an auto_increment there (otherwise InnoDB will create one internally and it will be an 8 byte int at that). On a moderately fast SSD, you shouldn't have any performance problems.

Comment: @N.B. +1 for pointing out the internal primary key issue. By and large my tables do have a unique key (which I understand is a special kind of primary key) so perhaps that is not an issue but I was not explicitly aware of this. I did some Googling and found [http://blog.jcole.us/2013/05/02/how-does-innodb-behave-without-a-primary-key/] + [http://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtradb-cluster/10603-limitations-on-tables-w-o-primary-keys].  I am using MariaDB 10 but from what I read the issue is also relevant there. B.T.W. the hidden P.K. is 6 not 8 bytes.

Comment: You do have a unique key, but it's not a primary one and it's not an integer - which is important in this case. You also use InnoDB, and InnoDB creates its index b-tree based on the primary key. In order to avoid lots of words, and it's covered much better elsewhere than what I can do right here and now - it's to do with write performance. Long story short, having an auto_increment there as a primary key can only benefit you, especially from performance point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you are not using a serial as your unique identifier? That would definitely be my first suggestion and would negate the necessity for the complicated setup you have.

Assuming that there is some reason then the biggest flaw I can see in your current makeUID call is that you are likely to get into a situation whereby the update sets 'used' to 1 and this row is deleted by a secondary call to makeUID before it has been able to successfully return the column meaning your second select (SELECT uid FROM `uidbank` WHERE used = '1') would return no rows

Could you explain why you dont use a serial so then I can try and get a better idea as to what is going on

Comment: There are excellent reasons for not using the serial as the UID.  Put quite simply the UID is not used only internally in the database but also in HTML markup that is generated from the objects stored by the user.  The UIDs there have to be alphanumeric strings and have to be globally unique - and bear a fixed pattern.

Comment: Would you therefore not be better off creating the UID within the php and using this in combination with a serial at the backend. If this isnt possible then the only way I can envisage is to use transactions and lock the table but this would have performance implications

Comment: I could not find a reasonable way to use my UID format for the outside world and use auto_increments internally.  At the same time transactions & table locking sounded excessive since UID collisions are really very rare events in the present context. So I ended up creating an ephemeral lock via MemCache. I use PHP 5.5 so try..finally gives a pretty secure solution. I have just simulated 1000 simultaneous hits with blitz.io and the system stands up with little perceptible performance degradation.